# The meaning of « un peu » in this context

Tags: sens

> C'est notre pays. Il nous appartient **un peu** à tous.

The speaker says this sentence, pointing out the fact that the country they live in does not just belong to a select few (as her interlocutor implies), but  to all the people there, in fact.

I wonder if « un peu » has the meaning of "kind of / sort of", taking the edge off the otherwise somewhat strong opinion?

> {compared to}: C'est notre pays. Il nous appartient à tous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means: this country is *a bit* mine, *a bit* yours, *a bit* hers, etc. for every person living in. Like every person owns a part of it.

To me there is no difference between the sentence with *un peu* and the other one. Maybe with *un peu* you insist on "every person" when with the other one you say "our community in its whole".

Comment: I agree with the slight difference. Using "un peu" means no one owns it all... not using "un peu" would mean "anyone could say « it's mine »"...